# Typing Indicators from facebook on Webhook URL

Tags: node.js, facebook, webhooks, chatbot

I am working on a Facebook connector in which messages from a Facebook page are sent to a Node.js server using a webhook. I successfully implemented this, and now I want to implement the typing indicator. When someone types on the messenger page, it sends a typing indicator to the webhook url so I can show on the other side that someone is typing. i already subscribe message and message_deliveries fields in my meta app.
I have no idea about Facebook sending or not Typing indicator notifications on the webhook.
If sent, then which subscription is used for this purpose while setting the webhook url in the meta app?

I tried documentation and chat_GPT but not still fail, expecting a solution for this or Facebook documentation solution.

Comment: I don't think they send any webhook updates for that. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webhooks#subscribe-to-meta-webhooks lists all the fields you can subscribe to, and the description of none of them has anything to do with a typing notification.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.